# Linking google perf tools for aarch64

Tags: c++, profiler, gperftools

I have been using google perf tools successfully on my pc. However, I am compiling and deploying for aarch64 architecture and the profiling results I get for x86 might not match up with aarch64.

I wanted to directly measure things on the aarch64 device. I compiled with `RelWithDebInfo` flag, I ran my code with run-time linking of profiler `LD_PRELOAD`.

For my first try, mostly I got addresses instead of function names:

```
 828   2.1%  86.0%      828   2.1% 0x0000007fa4ededb8
 827   2.1%  88.1%      827   2.1% 0x0000007fa4edcf5c
 641   1.6%  89.8%      641   1.6% 0x0000007fa4edcf6c
 600   1.5%  91.3%      600   1.5% 0x0000007fa4ededc4
 413   1.1%  92.4%      413   1.1% 0x0000007fa4edec5c
```

I got the real function names for some of the functions though.

`LD_PRELOAD` option is not recommended. On my x86 pc, I tried to link with `-lprofiler` option after compiling google performance tools doing:

```
./configure --prefix [AARCH64_LIBPATH] --host aarch64-gnu-linux
make && sudo make install
```

When I tried to `make` my code I got the following error:

```
skipping incompatible [AARCH64_LIBPATH]/libprofiler.so when searching for -lprofiler
[SOME_AARCH64_PATH]/ld: cannot find -lprofiler
```

How can I profile CPU on aarch64 device with google perf tools?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like debug info issue. Perhaps if you can provide small test program and exact details of how you run it, I will be able to help.